# Share Library between UWP App and .NET Core

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core

What is the best practice to share a library (also C# project) between Windows UWP app and a .NET Core web app?

I have the following solution setup starting from scratch:

- Solution

  - UWP App
  - Lib (With functionality I want to use in both other projects.)
  - .NET Core WebApp (2.2 or maybe 3.0)

As far as I could figure out, the only solution is, to create two projects for the lib, which share the same .cs files. But this feels a bit like a workaround and I am looking for a "clean(er)" way.

Comment: At the very least I believe you could use a shared project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. But my first impression is, replacing a workaround with another workaround. Is this such a rare scenario, that there is no direct way?

Comment: I think you are correct which is why I did not offer my solution as an answer. I wanted to give it to you in case no one else came up with a solution. I am aware of the solution @Gene proposed but have never used it with UWP so was not comfortable offering that solution either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share a .NET Standard 2.0 library between those projects, see [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

Note, that you cannot use any classes specific to .NET Core or the UWP in such a project.

[image: .NET Standard in VS2019]

Comment: Seems to be the only option. Since the good old .NET framework, .NET has become a real clutter.

Comment: Well, if you remember the times of Silverlight, Windows Phone and .NET Compact Framework, .NET Standard is actually a nice improvement.

Comment: Referencing a  .NET Standard 2.0 project in UWP requires targeting in UWP "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (16299)". If you are able you can lower the .NET Standard to 1.6, 1.4 ... -> See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: I am targeting Build 17763 (Version  1809)  At the moment it looks like everything works as expected. :)